# Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory

Tags: java, spring

I have the problem in my web services. It throws exception as below:

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext-datasource.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:389)
        at hk.com.xxx.util.ServiceLocator.getApplicationContext(ServiceLocator.java:25)
```

I have below code that show the problem:

```
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BeanFactoryLocator;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BeanFactoryReference;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator;

    public class ServiceLocator {
        private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        protected ServiceLocator() {
        }

        public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
            if (applicationContext == null) {
                BeanFactoryLocator locator = ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance("applicationContext.xml");
                BeanFactoryReference bfr = locator.useBeanFactory("applicationContext");
                BeanFactory factory = bfr.getFactory();
                applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) factory;
            }
            return applicationContext;
        }

    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="applicationContext"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>ApplicationContext-log4j.xml</value>
                <value>ApplicationContext-datasource.xml</value>                
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

ApplicationContext-datasource.xml --> extract one part that has problem

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="AS400ABC"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>hk/com/xxx/bls/dao/CategoryBean.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>hk/com/xxx/bls/dao/CustomerBillBean.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>hk/com/xxx/bls/dao/MerchantBean.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>hk/com/xxx/bls/dao/MerchantBillBean.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>hk/com/xxx/bls/dao/PaymentBean.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Then I google in the web and find that I need to add Apache Commons Pool 2.4.2 and Apache Commons DBCP 2.1.1 for JDBC 4.1 in the lib as noted in the link [I have trouble setting up spring hibernate application-context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585341/i-have-trouble-setting-up-spring-hibernate-application-context-xml).

I am not sure whether above is correct or not. If it is true, then now I meet another problem when I deployed the WAR in **weblogic clustering**. It shows below error : `java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerKey$$KeyFactoryByCGLIB$$7fb24d72 cannot be cast to net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory`.
In my lib, it is having asm.jar and cglib.jar as noted in the link http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/flex/65337-an-strange-error-with-net-sf-cglib-core-keyfactory.

What should I do??
I am using JDK7 on weblogic server 12.2.1.3

Comment: What are the versions of spring and cglib?

Comment: cglib -> 2.1.3 and spring -> 4.1